# Webservice times out after third call

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am developing a .NET plugin that translates some data from Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2013 into Json and sends it to a webservice on a clients server.

The webservice successfully transfers the first two times i call the send method but at the third call i recieve a timeout.

Ive searched the internet and discovered that this is due to not properly closing the webresponse but i cant seem to make it work.

The following code is a lightly modified version of my send method to display my issue.

Perhaps one of you can identify the problem that causes the third consecutive call to time out?

```
public string SendData(string schoolName)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + schoolName + ".*****.dk/api/v2/stays.json");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                string statusCode;
                return statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode + " " + "Eleven blev sendt til ******";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (httpResponse != null)
                {
                    httpResponse.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ive attemped to simplify the code as comments suggested but the issue still persists. The code now looks like this:

```
    public string SendData(string schoolName)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + schoolName + ".****.dk/api/v2/stays.json");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        using(HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            string statusCode;
            return statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode + " " + "Eleven blev sendt til ****";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your try/catch/finally is very complicated compared with just using a `using` statement... and you're assigning a local variable for no reason. Basically the second half of your method could be much, much simpler... are you sure you're *actually* closing the response in your real code? Usually problems like this are due to failing to dispose of a WebResponse. I note you're not disposing of the WebRequest, btw. `using` statements are your friend :)

Comment: @JonSkeet But does `WebRequest` even implement IDisposable? The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't mention it anywhere :s

Comment: It is complaining that it does not. It tells me type must be implicitly convertible to IDisposable.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry. I'd still use a `using` statement for the rest though - and if you close the `using` statement for the `StreamWriter` after the `Write` call, you don't need to call Flush and Close explicitly.

Comment: It turns out i had a minor error elsewhere in my project that ruined the call. The current code that i posted above with the help of you guys is correct and functioning. If you create an answer Jon Skeet i will mark it as solved. Thanks